# Integrate Google Protocol Buffers .proto files to Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, protocol-buffers

I've added a **custom build step** to my **Visual Studio** project files which generates the **google protobuf** .h/.cc files from the .proto input files. But I've been wondering if it's possible to start a compile only if the content of the proto files has changed?

Is there a way to tell VisualStudio from a custom build step exactly that? What is the optimal way to integrate proto files into a visual studio build solution?

At the moment, at every build the .proto file is updated which then also updates the time stamp of the output .h/.cc files ...which then issues a recompile of everything dependent from that. Is there a better way around it, while still building them directly from visual studio?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? It's a bit strange to ask and upvote a question without any discussion going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/msbuild/thread/f45b245c-45b1-4cbf-ad0c-fc63186ba41c) helps. Especially look at the post of Igor Zavoychinskiy:

> Solution of this nasty problem is actually simple: in outputs sections
>   you should specify full path(s). This isn't explicitly stated anywhere
>   but without this checker just fails to find the files and, hence,
>   assumes they don't exist. For example for protobuffers compiling
>   outputs section will be like this:
>
> $(InputDir)\$(InputName).pb.cc;$(InputDir)\$(InputName).pb.h

and (maybe?) kmote00:

> ...
>   Bottom line: I just had to make sure my "Outputs" entry exactly
>   matched the Default Value in the (user-defined) "OutputFile" property.
>   (Thankfully this also obviated the need for a two-pass build, which
>   was another annoyance I had previously put up with.)

Comment: This did help! Thank you @Jakob S. I had used relative paths for the outputs section.. and for some reason the $(InputDir)\$(InputName) is not definied... but aside from that. It works with absolute paths!

Comment: Okay... didn't know I had that option. Found it. Done! :) Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Follow these detailed instructions to specify [Custom Build Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Considering your proto file resides together with .h/.cpp files in standard project configuration, here are values to be inserted in Custom Build Tool:

```
Command Line: 
path\to\protoc --proto_path=$(ProjectDir) --cpp_out=$(ProjectDir) %(FullPath)
Outputs: 
$(ProjectDir)%(Filename).pb.h;$(ProjectDir)%(Filename).pb.cc
```

Please note usage of [item metadata macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164284%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)s, which replaced some of deprecated macros (like $(InputDir) and $(InputName)).

Now Protocol Buffers compiler will be run only when Input file (i.e. %(FullPath)) is newer than "Outputs".

Comment: My protoc.exe did not like '\' so I had to cd to the .proto file's directory and use `--cpp_out=./ %(FileName)%(Extension)`