# protobuf & visual studio seamless integration - monitor proto file changes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I am adding protobuf to my C++ project (for JSON reflection if you ask).
I want visual studio 2019 to listen to changes of my protobuf file(s) and compile them if the are newer than the generated c++ reflection of them. My question is -

How to make VS monitor changes in my `.proto` files, same way it monitors changes in C++ files. And when asked to compile, it will to run `protoc` before compiling.

*BTW, for future reference, I couldn't find working Nuget protobuf packages, which have both protoc.exe and the belonging headers, so I needed to use vcpkg.*

Comment: Add the generation as a custom build step on the protobuf file

Comment: you are correct sir.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447950/integrate-google-protocol-buffers-proto-files-to-visual-c-2010).
The way to do it is by adding a Custom Build Tool. see [here how to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-custom-build-tools?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

In a C# project we have done this by adding a Pre-build event in visual studio. The following example resembles our code:

```bsh
set FOLDER_PROTO=C:\Projecten\protobuf
set FOLDER_OUT=$(SolutionDir)\generated

mkdir %FOLDER_OUT%

for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b %FOLDER_PROTO%\msg\*.proto') do (
  protoc.exe -I=%FOLDER_PROTO% --cpp_out=%FOLDER_OUT% %%i
)
```

So all files are generated each time you build. There is another minor flaw, you have to add the source files to your solution manually. Maybe there is a command or wildcard you can use in your project to circumvent this.

Comment: This is what I've done. The problem is it doesn't monitor changes in my proto files as the trigger to create the cpp files. And that results in creating the cpp each time any change is made in any file in the project, causing long compilations.